# Restriction maps in the cohomology of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

The  [group wiki](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_elementary_abelian_group_of_prime-square_order) describes the cohomology groups $H^n(G,M)$ where $G=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$, $p$ is prime (I'm not sure how much this matters for that computation, but let's assume it), and $M$ has trivial $G$-action.

Specifically, if $n>0$:
$$H^n(G,M) \approx \left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
M[p]^{\frac{n+3}{2}}\oplus (M/pM)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
M[p]^{\frac{n}{2}}\oplus (M/pM)^{\frac{n+2}{2}} & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{array} \right.$$
where $M[p]$ is the $p$-torsion subgroup of $M$.

This involves various manipulations with the Künneth formula and the dual universal coefficient theorem, and the combinatorics become a little messy, especially since it requires some non-natural splitting of short exact sequence.

Now any $g\in G$ defines a morphism $f_g: \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to G$, and thus by restriction, a morphism
$$(f_g)^*: H^n(G,M)\to H^n(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}, M).$$
The good thing is that on the other hand $H^n(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}, M)$ is easy to understand: it is $M[p]$ when $n$ is odd, and $M/pM$ when $n$ is even (and nonzero).

> Is there a natural way to describe the maps
>   $$  M[p]^{\frac{n+3}{2}}\oplus (M/pM)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \to M[p] $$
>   (for $n$ odd) and
>   $$ M[p]^{\frac{n}{2}}\oplus (M/pM)^{\frac{n+2}{2}} \to M/pM$$
>   (for $n$ even) induced by each $g\in G$ (even though there are some non-natural choices in the description of the groups)?

As a corollary of how well they can be described, do they depend "nicely" on $g$? (Like, additively?)

For instance, in the case $n=1$, we are looking at a map $M[p]^2=\operatorname{Hom}(G,M)\to M[p]$, and this is just the evaluation at $g$.

I should specify that I am mainly interested in the case $n=3$, but I think understanding the general combinatorics can shed some light on the low-degree cases.

Comment: The image of the restriction map to a normal subgroup $H$ (which is the case here, since $G$ is abelian) lies in fact in $H^n(G,M)^{G/H}$. Maybe it can shed some light on the interpretation of the map you describe, but maybe not. I didn't do the computations.

Comment: @GreginGre You probably mean $H^n(H,M)^{G/H}$, but unfortunately since $G$ is abelian and the action on $M$ is trivial, the action of $G/H$ on $H^n(H,M)$ is trivial too, so this does not add any new information.